# My Gmail is lost and I can't find it anywhere

Tags: gmail, user-accounts

I literally lost my Gmail account. When I go to Gmail, only my daughter's pops up and mine is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're sharing a browser and aren't using multiple accounts with Google Multi-Login.

If you want to continue sharing the browser:

- Click your daughter's profile photo in the upper right
- Click "Add Account"
- Sign in to your account

Now you can switch between Google Accounts by clicking the profile photo and choosing the account you want to use.

If you *don't* with to continue sharing the browser:

- Click your daughter's profile photo in the upper right
- Click "Sign Out"
- Sign in to your account

Now your account should be the only one logged in, so when you go to `gmail.com` your email should be available to you.

Comment: If both your accounts were showing as options to sign in at one point, then the browser's history (or at least cookies) were cleared causing the screen to default back to Google's original sign in screen, at which point your daughter would have signed in and stored the cookie to keep her account listed.  Besides sharing a browser with multi-login enabled, you may also want to consider having separate user accounts on the computer itself.